# yii 1.1.16 application needs VPS not shared hosting, is that true?

Tags: yii, vps, yii1.x

I have a Yii 1.1.16 application previously developed by someone else.
I tried to host it on a shared environment (FatCow) but it produces several SMTP errors. I have spent multiple hours of my time reading remarks about this subject here, but no hope. The guy who developed it said this application should be hosted on VPS or a dedicated server or it will not work at all.

How true this is (it will not work on Shared host and it will work on VPS)?

The error: smtp error could not connect to smtp host
The SMTP is working fine outside the app.

Thank you in advance.
Luai

Answer (score 0):

Yii 1.1.16 is nohow limited to VPS. You can host it anywhere where you meed requirements.

It could be two possible issues:

- The application requires some specific SMPT configuration that is not provided by most shared hosts
- The application need to be reconfigured to use the SMTP setup from shared hosting where it is hosted

Comment: Thank you zmilan, I moved to VPS server, could you give me a hint what do you mean by SMTP configuration?

Comment: @Luai, most of the Yii1 applications use this extension https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mail for sending emails. I suppose it is similar to your one. It need config inside your config/main.php "components" key like this:
'mail' => array(
     'class' => 'application.extensions.mail.YiiMail',
     'transportType' => 'smtp',
    'transportOptions' => array(
     'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
     'username' => 'username',
     'password' => 'password',     
    ),
     'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail',
     'logging' => true,
     'dryRun' => false
    ),

Comment: Thank you zimilan. I have changed the SMTP configuration and updated the mail extension and now working perfectly.

Comment: Hi @Luai, you are welcome. I'm glad that it works :)

Answer (score 0):

@Zmilan was right.
After long days of hard work, SMTP and email are working fine.
I also found out that the application can work fine on shared hosting, but because it requires the Redis server and Redis PHP extension I had to move to VPS for further installations.